# CSS Create rounded indicator for selected menu item?

Tags: html, css

How to create a rounded indicator like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaDq1.png)?

This is for an active link tab indicator.
If the menu-item/tab is not active, it should be just a regular bar without the dot and the curve.

The selected indicator dot is above the selected/active menu item, and the surrounding area of the dot is transparent. There is also a slight curve on the toolbar.

Any ideas or help is much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an overlay from a picture, make it by positioning with a shift above the active button

[image]

[image]

```css
body {
  background: #acacac;
}

.header {
  height:40px;
  background: #EFEFF1;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.menu .item {
  height:60px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/Eg164mW_d.png) #0089F7;
  background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
  background-position-x: center;
  background-position-y: top;
}

.menu .item:hover {
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/Ac2kpWJ_d.png?maxwidth=800) #0089F7;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: center;
    background-position-y: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

</div>

<div class="menu">

  <div class="item">
    item 1
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    item 2
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    item 3
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. This is a great idea, unfortunately it does not work. The transparent part of the overlay ended up show the navbar behind it (as in your example, the red bar will be showing).

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the updated answer. I appreciate it!
As you suggested two overlays (dot for active, full rectangle for non-active), how do you make the horizontal div bar to have the square/rectangle holes on each section?